# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type without superclass: module-info

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

Criei um jogo com a libgdX e roda normalmente no celular emulador, mas agora para gerar o apk com chave ele não gera, estou perdendo um pouco de tempo com isso, alguém sabe a solução ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type without superclass: module-info
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:80)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(ClassVisitor.java:113)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visit(InterfaceDesugaring.java:97)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:621)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/sshd/server/Command
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.loadFromInternal(LambdaDesugaring.java:337)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.access$500(LambdaDesugaring.java:56)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.createLookup(LambdaDesugaring.java:620)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:402)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1623)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1126)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.sshd.server.Command not found
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more

:android:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input C:\Users\kaue\Documents\android
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passei pelo mesmo problema

Você pode usar o cruncherEnabled. No arquivo build.gradle

```
android
{
    aaptOptions
    {
    cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Espero que isso ajude você.